# What is the precise term for serving internal URLs to external ones?

Tags: url-rewriting, apache2, proxy

Consider URLs to a public API:

```
https://api.example.com/items
https://api.example.com/add
https://api.example.com/remove
...
```

Internally, the calls are being served from local URLs, for example: `1.2.3.4:8080/get_items`. In order to hide the internal URLs, there is a middleware that fetches the data from the internal URls and serves it to the external ones.

**What is the proper name for the middleware that fetches the information from the internal URL and serves it to the public API?**

"Proxy" seems to general, and "URL rewriter" seems too narrow.

Comment: are you on about binding the ip address to a physical domain name?

Comment: @LiamSorsby It's a part of the function - I am also mapping an external url to an internal one (e.g. `/items` to `/get_items`).

Comment: Ah so you are routing the urls in your API similar to how an MVC framework works?

Comment: Quick question /add & /remove are they not part of RESTful http spec i.e. requests using put, delete, POST, GET ect. I assume you are wanting to use a router to redirect the "method" to the script to execute the relevent query/script. I think however i am not really understand this question so i think i may leave it there and let someone else take over

Comment: You're right, it has nothing to do with REST - it's about the technical name of the url rewriting component. Fixed my question accordinglt.

Comment: @AdamMatan Based on your earlier question [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57879/when-should-a-node-js-application-be-placed-behind-a-web-server), I understood that you were running a separate internal server. Apache _mod_rewrite_ can be used to remove ports, but in this case, you'd need a proxy server. I'm therefore editing out _mod_rewrite_ because it might confuse others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the proper name for the middleware that fetches the
>   information from the internal URL and serves it to the public API?

A [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) or gateway:

> A reverse proxy is a type of proxy server that retrieves resources on
>   behalf of a client from one or more servers. These resources are then
>   returned to the client as though they originated from the server
>   itself (or servers themselves).

Also, see the Apache docs on [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html):

> A reverse proxy (or gateway) by contrast, appears to the client just
>   like an ordinary web server... The client makes ordinary requests for content in the
>   name-space of the reverse proxy. The reverse proxy then decides where
>   to send those requests, and returns the content as if it was itself
>   the origin.
>
> **A typical usage of a reverse proxy is to provide Internet users access
>   to a server that is behind a firewall.**